# Laravel returning wrong response

Tags: laravel

In my Controller I have the following code:

```
if (isset($request->validator) && $request->validator->fails()) 
{

   $a = 
        [
        "error_code" => 500, 
        "msg"   => 'The given data was invalid.', 
        "errors"    => $request->validator->errors()
        ];
        $a = implode(" ",$a);

        return back()->setStatusCode(422)->withErrors($request->validator->errors());


}
```

Basically, if the request form data was invalid, it is supposed to

- Send a htpp status code of 422
- Send the errors itemised

But the problem is that it is only obeying the first rule(about the htpp code) but not the second.

Ie it returns this:

```html
       <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://localhost:8000/dashboard/posts/create/?type=image" />
        
                <title>Redirecting to http://localhost:8000/dashboard/posts/create/?type=image</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost:8000/dashboard/posts/create/?type=image">http://localhost:8000/dashboard/posts/create/?type=image</a>.
            <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' property='stylesheet' href='//localhost:8000/_debugbar/assets/stylesheets?v=1561562319'><script type='text/javascript' src='//localhost:8000/_debugbar/assets/javascript?v=1561562319'></script><script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
        <script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild || doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle); if (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function (e) { e.preventDefault = function () {e.returnValue = false;}; e.target = e.srcElement; callback(e); }); }; } function toggle(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className, arrow, newClass; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '▼'; newClass = 'sf-dump-expanded'; } else if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '▶'; newClass = 'sf-dump-compact'; } else { return false; } if (doc.createEvent && s.dispatchEvent) { var event = doc.createEvent('Event'); event.initEvent('sf-dump-expanded' === newClass ? 'sfbeforedumpexpand' : 'sfbeforedumpcollapse', true, false); s.dispatchEvent(event); } a.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; s.className = s.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-(compact|expanded)\b/, newClass); if (recursive) { try { a = s.querySelectorAll('.'+oldClass); for (s = 0; s < a.length; ++s) { if (-1 == a[s].className.indexOf(newClass)) { a[s].className = newClass; a[s].previousSibling.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; } } } catch (e) { } } return true; }; function collapse(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function expand(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return true; } return false; }; function collapseAll(root) { var a = root.querySelector('a.sf-dump-toggle'); if (a) { collapse(a, true); expand(a); return true; } return false; } function reveal(node) { var previous, parents = []; while ((node = node.parentNode || {}) && (previous = node.previousSibling) && 'A' === previous.tagName) { parents.push(previous); } if (0 !== parents.length) { parents.forEach(function (parent) { expand(parent); }); return true; } return false; } function highlight(root, activeNode, nodes) { resetHighlightedNodes(root); Array.from(nodes||[]).forEach(function (node) { if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/.test(node.className)) { node.className = node.className + ' sf-dump-highlight'; } }); if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/.test(activeNode.className)) { activeNode.className = activeNode.className + ' sf-dump-highlight-active'; } } function resetHighlightedNodes(root) { Array.from(root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str, .sf-dump-key, .sf-dump-public, .sf-dump-protected, .sf-dump-private')).forEach(function (strNode) { strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/, ''); strNode.className = strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/, ''); }); } return function (root, x) { root = doc.getElementById(root); var indentRx = new RegExp('^('+(root.getAttribute('data-indent-pad') || ' ').replace(rxEsc, '\\$1')+')+', 'm'), options = {"maxDepth":1,"maxStringLength":160,"fileLinkFormat":false}, elt = root.getElementsByTagName('A'), len = elt.length, i = 0, s, h, t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); for (i in x) { options[i] = x[i]; } function a(e, f) { addEventListener(root, e, function (e) { if ('A' == e.target.tagName) { f(e.target, e); } else if ('A' == e.target.parentNode.tagName) { f(e.target.parentNode, e); } else if (e.target.nextElementSibling && 'A' == e.target.nextElementSibling.tagName) { f(e.target.nextElementSibling, e, true); } }); }; function isCtrlKey(e) { return e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey; } function xpathString(str) { var parts = str.match(/[^'"]+|['"]/g).map(function (part) { if ("'" == part) { return '"\'"'; } if ('"' == part) { return "'\"'"; } return "'" + part + "'"; }); return "concat(" + parts.join(",") + ", '')"; } function xpathHasClass(className) { return "contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' " + className +" ')"; } addEventListener(root, 'mouseover', function (e) { if ('' != refStyle.innerHTML) { refStyle.innerHTML = ''; } }); a('mouseover', function (a, e, c) { if (c) { e.target.style.cursor = "pointer"; } else if (a = idRx.exec(a.className)) { try { refStyle.innerHTML = '.phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .'+a[0]+'{background-color: #B729D9; color: #FFF !important; border-radius: 2px}'; } catch (e) { } } }); a('click', function (a, e, c) { if (/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); if (!toggle(a, isCtrlKey(e))) { var r = doc.getElementById(a.getAttribute('href').substr(1)), s = r.previousSibling, f = r.parentNode, t = a.parentNode; t.replaceChild(r, a); f.replaceChild(a, s); t.insertBefore(s, r); f = f.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); t = t.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); if (f && t && f[0] !== t[0]) { r.innerHTML = r.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('^'+f[0].replace(rxEsc, '\\$1'), 'mg'), t[0]); } if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(r.className)) { toggle(s, isCtrlKey(e)); } } if (c) { } else if (doc.getSelection) { try { doc.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); } catch (e) { doc.getSelection().empty(); } } else { doc.selection.empty(); } } else if (/\bsf-dump-str-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); e = a.parentNode.parentNode; e.className = e.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-str-(expand|collapse)\b/, a.parentNode.className); } }); elt = root.getElementsByTagName('SAMP'); len = elt.length; i = 0; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); len = t.length; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { elt = t[i]; if ('SAMP' == elt.tagName) { a = elt.previousSibling || {}; if ('A' != a.tagName) { a = doc.createElement('A'); a.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; elt.parentNode.insertBefore(a, elt); } else { a.innerHTML += ' '; } a.title = (a.title ? a.title+'\n[' : '[')+keyHint+'+click] Expand all children'; a.innerHTML += '<span>▼</span>'; a.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; x = 1; if ('sf-dump' != elt.parentNode.className) { x += elt.parentNode.getAttribute('data-depth')/1; } elt.setAttribute('data-depth', x); var className = elt.className; elt.className = 'sf-dump-expanded'; if (className ? 'sf-dump-expanded' !== className : (x > options.maxDepth)) { toggle(a); } } else if (/\bsf-dump-ref\b/.test(elt.className) && (a = elt.getAttribute('href'))) { a = a.substr(1); elt.className += ' '+a; if (/[\[{]$/.test(elt.previousSibling.nodeValue)) { a = a != elt.nextSibling.id && doc.getElementById(a); try { s = a.nextSibling; elt.appendChild(a); s.parentNode.insertBefore(a, s); if (/^[@#]/.test(elt.innerHTML)) { elt.innerHTML += ' <span>▶</span>'; } else { elt.innerHTML = '<span>▶</span>'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } elt.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; } catch (e) { if ('&' == elt.innerHTML.charAt(0)) { elt.innerHTML = '…'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } } } } } if (doc.evaluate && Array.from && root.children.length > 1) { root.setAttribute('tabindex', 0); SearchState = function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; }; SearchState.prototype = { next: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return this.current(); } this.idx = this.idx < (this.nodes.length - 1) ? this.idx + 1 : 0; return this.current(); }, previous: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return this.current(); } this.idx = this.idx > 0 ? this.idx - 1 : (this.nodes.length - 1); return this.current(); }, isEmpty: function () { return 0 === this.count(); }, current: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return null; } return this.nodes[this.idx]; }, reset: function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; }, count: function () { return this.nodes.length; }, }; function showCurrent(state) { var currentNode = state.current(), currentRect, searchRect; if (currentNode) { reveal(currentNode); highlight(root, currentNode, state.nodes); if ('scrollIntoView' in currentNode) { currentNode.scrollIntoView(true); currentRect = currentNode.getBoundingClientRect(); searchRect = search.getBoundingClientRect(); if (currentRect.top < (searchRect.top + searchRect.height)) { window.scrollBy(0, -(searchRect.top + searchRect.height + 5)); } } } counter.textContent = (state.isEmpty() ? 0 : state.idx + 1) + ' of ' + state.count(); } var search = doc.createElement('div'); search.className = 'sf-dump-search-wrapper sf-dump-search-hidden'; search.innerHTML = ' <input type="text" class="sf-dump-search-input"> <span class="sf-dump-search-count">0 of 0<\/span> <button type="button" class="sf-dump-search-input-previous" tabindex="-1"> <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1683 1331l-166 165q-19 19-45 19t-45-19L896 965l-531 531q-19 19-45 19t-45-19l-166-165q-19-19-19-45.5t19-45.5l742-741q19-19 45-19t45 19l742 741q19 19 19 45.5t-19 45.5z"\/><\/svg> <\/button> <button type="button" class="sf-dump-search-input-next" tabindex="-1"> <svg viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1683 808l-742 741q-19 19-45 19t-45-19L109 808q-19-19-19-45.5t19-45.5l166-165q19-19 45-19t45 19l531 531 531-531q19-19 45-19t45 19l166 165q19 19 19 45.5t-19 45.5z"\/><\/svg> <\/button> '; root.insertBefore(search, root.firstChild); var state = new SearchState(); var searchInput = search.querySelector('.sf-dump-search-input'); var counter = search.querySelector('.sf-dump-search-count'); var searchInputTimer = 0; var previousSearchQuery = ''; addEventListener(searchInput, 'keyup', function (e) { var searchQuery = e.target.value; /* Don't perform anything if the pressed key didn't change the query */ if (searchQuery === previousSearchQuery) { return; } previousSearchQuery = searchQuery; clearTimeout(searchInputTimer); searchInputTimer = setTimeout(function () { state.reset(); collapseAll(root); resetHighlightedNodes(root); if ('' === searchQuery) { counter.textContent = '0 of 0'; return; } var classMatches = [ "sf-dump-str", "sf-dump-key", "sf-dump-public", "sf-dump-protected", "sf-dump-private", ].map(xpathHasClass).join(' or '); var xpathResult = doc.evaluate('.//span[' + classMatches + '][contains(translate(child::text(), ' + xpathString(searchQuery.toUpperCase()) + ', ' + xpathString(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) + '), ' + xpathString(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) + ')]', root, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null); while (node = xpathResult.iterateNext()) state.nodes.push(node); showCurrent(state); }, 400); }); Array.from(search.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-search-input-next, .sf-dump-search-input-previous')).forEach(function (btn) { addEventListener(btn, 'click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); -1 !== e.target.className.indexOf('next') ? state.next() : state.previous(); searchInput.focus(); collapseAll(root); showCurrent(state); }) }); addEventListener(root, 'keydown', function (e) { var isSearchActive = !/\bsf-dump-search-hidden\b/.test(search.className); if ((114 === e.keyCode && !isSearchActive) || (isCtrlKey(e) && 70 === e.keyCode)) { /* F3 or CMD/CTRL + F */ e.preventDefault(); search.className = search.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-search-hidden\b/, ''); searchInput.focus(); } else if (isSearchActive) { if (27 === e.keyCode) { /* ESC key */ search.className += ' sf-dump-search-hidden'; e.preventDefault(); resetHighlightedNodes(root); searchInput.value = ''; } else if ( (isCtrlKey(e) && 71 === e.keyCode) /* CMD/CTRL + G */ || 13 === e.keyCode /* Enter */ || 114 === e.keyCode /* F3 */ ) { e.preventDefault(); e.shiftKey ? state.previous() : state.next(); collapseAll(root); showCurrent(state); } } }); } if (0 >= options.maxStringLength) { return; } try { elt = root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str'); len = elt.length; i = 0; t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); len = t.length; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { elt = t[i]; s = elt.innerText || elt.textContent; x = s.length - options.maxStringLength; if (0 < x) { h = elt.innerHTML; elt[elt.innerText ? 'innerText' : 'textContent'] = s.substring(0, options.maxStringLength); elt.className += ' sf-dump-str-collapse'; elt.innerHTML = '<span class=sf-dump-str-collapse>'+h+'<a class="sf-dump-ref sf-dump-str-toggle" title="Collapse"> ◀</a></span>'+ '<span class=sf-dump-str-expand>'+elt.innerHTML+'<a class="sf-dump-ref sf-dump-str-toggle" title="'+x+' remaining characters"> ▶</a></span>'; } } } catch (e) { } }; })(document); </script><style> .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump { display: block; white-space: pre; padding: 5px; overflow: initial !important; } .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump:after { content: ""; visibility: hidden; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; } .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump span { display: inline; } .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-compact { display: none; } .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump abbr { text-decoration: none; border: none; cursor: help; } .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump a { text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; border: 0; outline: none; color: inherit; } .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis { display: inline-block; overflow: visible; text-overflow: ellipsis; max-width: 5em; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: top; } .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis+.sf-dump-ellipsis { max-width: none; } .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump code { display:inline; padding:0; background:none; } .sf-dump-str-collapse .sf-dump-str-collapse { display: none; } .sf-dump-str-expand .sf-dump-str-expand { display: none; } .sf-dump-public.sf-dump-highlight, .sf-dump-protected.sf-dump-highlight, .sf-dump-private.sf-dump-highlight, .sf-dump-str.sf-dump-highlight, .sf-dump-key.sf-dump-highlight { background: rgba(111, 172, 204, 0.3); border: 1px solid #7DA0B1; border-radius: 3px; } .sf-dump-public.sf-dump-highlight-active, .sf-dump-protected.sf-dump-highlight-active, .sf-dump-private.sf-dump-highlight-active, .sf-dump-str.sf-dump-highlight-active, .sf-dump-key.sf-dump-highlight-active { background: rgba(253, 175, 0, 0.4); border: 1px solid #ffa500; border-radius: 3px; } .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-hidden { display: none !important; } .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper { font-size: 0; white-space: nowrap; margin-bottom: 5px; display: flex; position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; top: 5px; } .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > * { vertical-align: top; box-sizing: border-box; height: 21px; font-weight: normal; border-radius: 0; background: #FFF; color: #757575; border: 1px solid #BBB; } .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > input.sf-dump-search-input { padding: 3px; height: 21px; font-size: 12px; border-right: none; border-top-left-radius: 3px; border-bottom-left-radius: 3px; color: #000; min-width: 15px; width: 100%; } .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-next, .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-previous { background: #F2F2F2; outline: none; border-left: none; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; } .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-next { border-top-right-radius: 3px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; } .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-next > svg, .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-previous > svg { pointer-events: none; width: 12px; height: 12px; } .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-count { display: inline-block; padding: 0 5px; margin: 0; border-left: none; line-height: 21px; font-size: 12px; }.phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump, .phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-default{word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: normal}.phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-num{font-weight:bold; color:#1299DA}.phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-const{font-weight:bold}.phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-str{font-weight:bold; color:#3A9B26}.phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-note{color:#1299DA}.phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ref{color:#7B7B7B}.phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-public{color:#000000}.phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-protected{color:#000000}.phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-private{color:#000000}.phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-meta{color:#B729D9}.phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-key{color:#3A9B26}.phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-index{color:#1299DA}.phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis{color:#A0A000}.phpdebugbar pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ns{user-select:none;}</style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var phpdebugbar = new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar();
        phpdebugbar.addIndicator("php_version", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Indicator({"icon":"code","tooltip":"Version"}), "right");
        phpdebugbar.addTab("messages", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"list-alt","title":"Messages", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.MessagesWidget()}));
        phpdebugbar.addIndicator("time", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Indicator({"icon":"clock-o","tooltip":"Request Duration"}), "right");
        phpdebugbar.addTab("timeline", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"tasks","title":"Timeline", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.TimelineWidget()}));
        phpdebugbar.addIndicator("memory", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Indicator({"icon":"cogs","tooltip":"Memory Usage"}), "right");
        phpdebugbar.addTab("exceptions", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"bug","title":"Exceptions", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.ExceptionsWidget()}));
        phpdebugbar.addTab("views", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"leaf","title":"Views", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.TemplatesWidget()}));
        phpdebugbar.addTab("route", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"share","title":"Route", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.VariableListWidget()}));
        phpdebugbar.addIndicator("currentroute", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Indicator({"icon":"share","tooltip":"Route"}), "right");
        phpdebugbar.addTab("queries", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"database","title":"Queries", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.LaravelSQLQueriesWidget()}));
        phpdebugbar.addTab("emails", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"inbox","title":"Mails", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.MailsWidget()}));
        phpdebugbar.addTab("auth", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"lock","title":"Auth", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.VariableListWidget()}));
        phpdebugbar.addIndicator("auth.name", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Indicator({"icon":"user","tooltip":"Auth status"}), "right");
        phpdebugbar.addTab("gate", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"list-alt","title":"Gate", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.MessagesWidget()}));
        phpdebugbar.addTab("session", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"archive","title":"Session", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.VariableListWidget()}));
        phpdebugbar.addTab("request", new PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Tab({"icon":"tags","title":"Request", "widget": new PhpDebugBar.Widgets.HtmlVariableListWidget()}));
        phpdebugbar.setDataMap({
        "php_version": ["php.version", ],
        "messages": ["messages.messages", []],
        "messages:badge": ["messages.count", null],
        "time": ["time.duration_str", '0ms'],
        "timeline": ["time", {}],
        "memory": ["memory.peak_usage_str", '0B'],
        "exceptions": ["exceptions.exceptions", []],
        "exceptions:badge": ["exceptions.count", null],
        "views": ["views", []],
        "views:badge": ["views.nb_templates", 0],
        "route": ["route", {}],
        "currentroute": ["route.uri", ],
        "queries": ["queries", []],
        "queries:badge": ["queries.nb_statements", 0],
        "emails": ["swiftmailer_mails.mails", []],
        "emails:badge": ["swiftmailer_mails.count", null],
        "auth": ["auth.guards", {}],
        "auth.name": ["auth.names", ],
        "gate": ["gate.messages", []],
        "gate:badge": ["gate.count", null],
        "session": ["session", {}],
        "request": ["request", {}]
        });
        phpdebugbar.restoreState();
        phpdebugbar.ajaxHandler = new PhpDebugBar.AjaxHandler(phpdebugbar, undefined, true);
        phpdebugbar.ajaxHandler.bindToXHR();
        phpdebugbar.setOpenHandler(new PhpDebugBar.OpenHandler({"url":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/_debugbar\/open"}));
        phpdebugbar.addDataSet({"__meta":{"id":"Xd39066258b4a2621a0ed4dcd084f5d32","datetime":"2019-06-27 06:31:41","utime":1561617101.172856,"method":"POST","uri":"\/upload","ip":"127.0.0.1"},"php":{"version":"7.3.1","interface":"cli-server"},"messages":{"count":0,"messages":[]},"time":{"start":1561617100.455814,"end":1561617101.172856,"duration":0.7170422077178955,"duration_str":"717.04ms","measures":[{"label":"Booting","start":1561617100.455814,"relative_start":0,"end":1561617100.836836,"relative_end":1561617100.836836,"duration":0.38102221488952637,"duration_str":"381.02ms","params":[],"collector":null},{"label":"Application","start":1561617100.852837,"relative_start":0.39702320098876953,"end":1561617101.172856,"relative_end":0,"duration":0.320019006729126,"duration_str":"320.02ms","params":[],"collector":null}]},"memory":{"peak_usage":12164672,"peak_usage_str":"11.6MB"},"exceptions":{"count":0,"exceptions":[]},"views":{"nb_templates":0,"templates":[]},"route":{"uri":"POST upload","middleware":"web","controller":"App\\Http\\Controllers\\PostController@upload","namespace":"App\\Http\\Controllers","prefix":null,"where":[],"as":"upload","file":"\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\PostController.php:360-468"},"queries":{"nb_statements":1,"nb_failed_statements":0,"accumulated_duration":0.017,"accumulated_duration_str":"17ms","statements":[{"sql":"select * from `users` where `id` = 15 limit 1","type":"query","params":[],"bindings":["15"],"hints":["Use <code>SELECT *<\/code> only if you need all columns from table","<code>LIMIT<\/code> without <code>ORDER BY<\/code> causes non-deterministic results, depending on the query execution plan"],"backtrace":[{"index":15,"namespace":null,"name":"\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\EloquentUserProvider.php","line":52},{"index":16,"namespace":null,"name":"\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\SessionGuard.php","line":131},{"index":17,"namespace":null,"name":"\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\GuardHelpers.php","line":60},{"index":18,"namespace":null,"name":"\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthManager.php","line":292},{"index":19,"namespace":null,"name":"\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade.php","line":223},{"index":20,"namespace":null,"name":"\\app\\Http\\Requests\\StorePostRequest.php","line":17},{"index":23,"namespace":null,"name":"\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php","line":87},{"index":24,"namespace":null,"name":"\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\
```

I'm guessing it has do with phpdebugbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages are stored in the session. To display them you need to access the session in your blade file like `{{session('errors')->first('error1')}}`.

Take a look at [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/use-witherrors-without-validator) post for more examples.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but I'm pretty sure that that is not the problem

Comment: I hink it has to do with `phpdebugbar` blocking the errors or something

Comment: If that's what you think you probably have already tried with the debugbar disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the [phpdebugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar).

```
\Debugbar::disable();
```